# How can I get NSLog to do a better job at describing the contents of an array?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My console output looks like this:

```
2011-12-07 02:46:48.051 Calculator[13186:f803] Operand pushed to stack: 23
2011-12-07 02:46:48.052 Calculator[13186:f803] programStack = (
23
)
2011-12-07 02:46:50.540 Calculator[13186:f803] Operand pushed to stack: 39
2011-12-07 02:46:50.541 Calculator[13186:f803] programStack = (
23,
39
)
2011-12-07 02:47:07.930 Calculator[13186:f803] Calculator Cleared!
2011-12-07 02:47:07.931 Calculator[13186:f803] programStack = (
)
```

I'm using this line to describe the stack: `NSLog(@"programStack: %@", stack);`

My intention is to get the console to show something like

```
programStack = (23)
```

and of course with more items inside to be like

```
programStack = (23, 7, 2473, 23.324, 888)
```

Why is it that the console describes arrays so clumsily by default?

Comment: Thank you both!
So I've decided to write my own describeStack method. Now, NSLog inserts a hard carriage return implicitly. To achieve what I want, I need exactly that to NOT happen.
There is no way to force NSLog to NOT insert a carriage return when called, right?
I want to do this so I can describe an array with objects of type NSNumber and NSString on ONE LINE, so I do make use of the fact that NSLog can describe objects by calling their built-in "describe" method, as both of you pointed out.

Comment: Note, if you want others to know you've let a comment on a post that isn't theirs, you need to put this @QwertyBob. How does removing the trailing `\n` help? Just loop through the items of the array and append their value to a temporary `NSMutableString`. You have full control over the content of this `NSMutableString`, then send that to `NSLog()`.

Comment: @QwertyBob Thanks a ton for the tip! Didn't know that.
And that's a perfect solution, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSLog` isn't the one truly transforming the array into the format that's printed. `NSArray` is the one describing itself that way. When objects are passed to NSLog, it calls [`description`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description) to get an `NSString` representation of the object.

So if you really wanted to change how arrays are described you could :

- subclass NSArray to override `description`.  (Not the preferred option as you'd miss out on NSMutableArrays which are themselves subclasses of NSArray amongst other things)
- get the array's description directly and remove any carriage return/line from the string before passing it to NSLog.  (Not the best solution either because it's not forward-compatible.  If ever the array describes itself differently this fails.)
- or iterate through the objects of the array yourself and generate your desired output. (Your safest bet)

Either way, you'll have to generate it yourself.

I personally enjoy how NSArray and NSDictionary describe themselves, especially when they contain more arrays and dictionaries : everything is nicely indented.

Answer (score 2):

NSLog calls the classes description method, write your own method for programStack.